# .htaccess mod_rewrite with multiple variable in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a search that create a query string for MySQL and show the result. The thing is that the query doesn't have the same length of variable each time a search is made.

I was wondering if in .htaccess it's possible to make a mod_rewrite depending on how much variable I throw at it.

Instead of having this in the URL

```
results.php?var1=something&var2=something&var3=.....
```

I get this

```
results/var1/something/var2/something/var3/something...
```

But remember that the numbers of vars can change depending on which checkboxes are checked by the user on the search form.

I hope it's clear if not I'll try to add more example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)$ /results/$3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^results/$ /results.php [L,QSA,R]
```

The first rule will loop as long as there are `/var/something` pairs in the URI, and keeps appending them on the query string. When finally there are no more pairs left, the `results/` gets rewritten to `results.php`.