# .htaccess mod_rewrite Unknown number of Variables of a GET form

Tags: php, html, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**What I'm doing:**

I'm creating a search with advanced filters (lots of checkboxes) and I'm using that PHP feature of giving all of them same name with [] at end. Here is an simplified example:

*(HTML)*

```
<h3>Elements</h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="elementPicked[]" value="1" checked="checked" /> Fire</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="elementPicked[]" value="2" checked="checked" /> Water</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="elementPicked[]" value="3" checked="checked" /> Wind</label>

<h3>Rarity</h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="rarityPicked[]" value="10,11,12" /> Common</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="rarityPicked[]" value="19,20,21,22" /> Uncommon</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="rarityPicked[]" value="29,30,31,32" /> Rare</label>

<!-- (...other somethingPicked[] types, like atk, def and cost...) -->
```

*(PHP)*

```
if(!empty($_GET['elementPicked'])) {
    foreach($_GET['elementPicked'] as $elementPicked) {
        //do something with each $elementPicked
    }
}
```

For the mod_rewrite, currently my rewrite works as following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Example: ./
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [NC,L]

#Example: ./p/dashboard
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]*)$ index.php?z=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This means that if i call `http://example.com`, it will rewrite to call `http://example.com/index.php`.

And if i call `http://example.com/p/cardlist`, it will rewrite to call `http://example.com/index.php?z=cardlist`.
Pretty easy this one.

**So, now the htaccess problem:**

For this form, the URL gets like this:
`http://example.com/p/carddisplay?elementPicked%5B%5D=1&elementPicked%5B%5D=2&elementPicked%5B%5D=3&rarityType=Select&rarityPicked%5B%5D=39%2C40%2C41%2C42&rarityPicked%5B%5D=49%2C50%2C51%2C52`
Since is a search and people could come to the same url later, POST is not an option (it would not 'save' the chosen checkboxes for other session).

What I wanted to achieve was `http://example.com/p/carddisplay/var1/something/var2/something/var3/something...` or translating the above example, `http://example.com/p/carddisplay/elementPicked%5B%5D/1/elementPicked%5B%5D/2/elementPicked%5B%5D/3/rarityType/Select/rarityPicked%5B%5D/39%2C40%2C41%2C42/rarityPicked%5B%5D/49%2C50%2C51%2C52` (or if can remove the url-encoded [] would be awesome too because is still ugly as hell.. Any suggestions for getting it prettier are welcome).

I found something INVERSE to what I wanted here -> [.htaccess mod_rewrite with multiple variable in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217261/htaccess-mod-rewrite-with-multiple-variable-in-url)

But anyways, I couldn't make it work messing with it, because I have more than one `var[]`. *Is this actually possible to achieve with rewrite?*

Comment: I am wondering if the URL really has to be SEO friendly?

Comment: @SalmanA I just didn't wanted to use post as I wanted user to be able to comeback to the result page anytime. And yeah, I was wondering if I should just give up the idea of making friendlier URL in a search. Now that I think again, seems a dumb idea, right? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the variables one by one in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and loop on that

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# capture query string variables
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?)=(.+?)&(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?p/carddisplay.*$ $0/%1/%2?%3 [L]

# capture last variable and redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?)=(.+?)$
RewriteRule ^/?p/carddisplay.*$ $0/%1/%2? [R,L]

# redirect URL with empty query string to index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?p/(.*)$ index.php?z=$1 [NC,L]
```

This loops as long as there's a query string and builds up the new URL, then sends a redirect to the client.

If you want to remove `[]/%5B%5D`, change the RewriteCond to something like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?)%5B%5D=(.+?)(?:&(.*))?$
```

#### What happens here?

When a request `/p/carddisplay?var1=value1&var2=value2` comes from a form, the browser is first redirected to `/p/carddisplay/var1/value1/var2/value2`. When the browser then requests this URL, it is rewritten and internally redirected to `index.php?z=carddisplay/var1/value1/var2/value2`.

This calls the PHP page `index.php` with just one `$_GET['z']` parameter, which has the value `carddisplay/var1/value1/var2/value2`.

Any other request starting with `/p/...` is internally redirected to `index.php?z=...` without the remaining parameters.

Comment: If I put before my htaccess' `#Example: ./`,form submission still goes to `http://192.168.1.150/aeria.immortalis.index/p/carddisplay?elementPicked%5B%5D=1&elementPicked%5B%5D=2&elementPicked%5B%5D=3` but server returns "Object not found!"(404).If I put after `RewriteRule ^p/([^/]*)$ index.php?z=$1 [NC,L]`,form submission still goes to `http://192.168.1.150/aeria.immortalis.index/p/carddisplay?elementPicked%5B%5D=1&elementPicked%5B%5D=2&elementPicked%5B%5D=3` like it does not exists/didn't entered in the condition. I tried removing that `/?` from `^/?p/` but no changes on the behavior described

Comment: @RaphaelDDL I changed my answer according to your comments and incorporated your existing rule. I hope, I got it right this time.

Comment: Thanks for trying :) But now no pages work except by index. I believe all pages are query string also since I'm transforming `http://example.com/index.php?z=somepage` into `http://example.com/p/somepage`, no?

Comment: @RaphaelDDL No, `http://example.com/index.php?z=somepage` is not changed. It stays that way and will call the PHP page. I thought `/p/carddisplay` is the only URL, you want to change.

Comment: What I meant by the last comment is that with your new code, my `http://example.com/p/somepage` do not work anymore. MY code `RewriteRule ^p/([^/]*)$ index.php?z=$1 [NC,L,QSA]` transforms this request `http://example.com/p/somepage` into `http://example.com/index.php?z=somepage` for the server. With your code, only `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com/index.php` works, while carddisplay does not even open.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Do you want any `/p/somepage` behave like `/p/carddisplay`?

Comment: Nope. All pages are `/p/something` where `something` is a GET value that is the name of the php page to be included on index.php. I was thinking maybe I wasn't clear enough: I want a way that when I submit the form on `/p/cardlist` that points to `/p/carddisplay`, the url on browser shows as `/p/carddisplay/var/value/var/value` instead of `/p/carddisplay?var=value&var=value`. The other answer (user deleted it) said that I should use JS to actually mount this kind of URL I want and just use your htaccess to make php correctly reads it as GET.Is that right? And btw,thanks for all help until now.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL I tried explaining the current state. Please look, whether this is what you need or if I must change the rules to better fit your scenario.

Comment: Now I got it. So in the end, the variable `z` will have the `carddisplay/var1/value1/var2/value2` and I'll just need  to explode it prior to calling the page! Will test the code on htaccess again with the correct explode on z and let you know if was all ok! Thanks for your time explaining to me.