# htaccess rewrite for multiple query string with one dynamic empty query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I ran into an issue with query strings and rewriting them to seem "prettier"
My website is at: localhost/admin/ so when uploaded to my server it is also under the /admin directory, and the .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect URL with empty query string to index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /admin/index.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

Unfortunately, my design for the admin panel all of the pages are linked to the index.php file. So when I originally used to request http://localhost/admin/?users it would show a list of all of the users. I wanted to make this prettier so I used the above htaccess rules and came up with http://localhost/admin/users. Two issues arose with this:

1. The css files within the admin folder under css/ could not be accessed so none of the styles were being applied.
2. This ?users page contains pagination using the GET parameter in php as well, so it looks kind of like http://localhost/admin/users&page=1 and used to look like http://localhost/admin/?users&page=2.

So basically what I wanted to do was make the code look more like this: http://localhost/admin/users/page/1. Unfortunately I cannot hard code the users parameter in because I have other sections like "websites" and I will also have a edit users page with id's etc. So I was wondering if someone could help me with the best way to approach this problem or how I can fix the above htaccess rules? The only thing that kind of helped was: [.htaccess mod_rewrite Unknown number of Variables of a GET form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651110/htaccess-mod-rewrite-unknown-number-of-variables-of-a-get-form) but I am still lost on how to implement it for multiple empty GET variables at the front of the url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do,

First for css part use `<base href="domain.com/">` in head section of your pages.

You are redirecting full url to query string of index.php and I am assuming you are retrieving is as `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`.

So I suggest you that you change your pagination url to `http://localhost/admin/users/page/1`.

And after that when you retrieve them in index.php explode the string using explode function,

```
$arr = explode('/',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Inside your `$arr` you will have all your values which you got them from query string.